# What does "to rock a club" mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions

It's a line from Taio Cruz's song *Dynamite*:

> Cause we gon' **rock this club**
>   We gon' go all night
>   We gon' light it up
>   Like it's dynamite

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpreting lyrics. FWIW, this figurative usage means *"We're going to make this clubhouse **liven up, be more exciting/excited**"*. Deriving from figurative *to rock = to destablise, astonish, surprise, shock*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I do know that when Norwich City are beating Manchester United (sometimes happens) Carrow  Road is *rocking*. Football commentators use *rocking* in that sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers sounds like you're contradicting yourself. You know what the meaning is, and you mention it, but you also say it's impossible to know? Huh? It's pretty obvious to any native speaker what "rock this club" means. There's not much room for interpretation here, and even if there were, since any native speaker would assume "rock the club" means "excite the club", it doesn't really matter. Methinks this site's rules are too strict if this question really is considered off-topic.

Comment: @sgroves: There's plenty of room for interpretation. When I wrote that first comment I was just expressing my opinion at the time (that the lyricist meant *We will make this club exciting*). On another day in another universe I might have suggested it meant *We will **disrupt** this club*. But you say ***any** native speaker would assume* the same meaning, which to my mind would automatically make the question Off Topic anyway - things that all native speakers know (but some nns don't) must surely belong on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), not ELU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Webster's](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rock), to rock means "to rouse to excitement (as by performing rock music)". [Cambridge's American-English](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/rock) further supports this definition. As we can tell in the context, they (the we mentioned in the song) are going to excite the club.